# Django - request.is_secure always returns False

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm running a Django project on a DigitalOcean VPS using Nginx and Gunicorn. I made sure that i'm using HTTPS, but for some reason using `request.is_secure()` always returns `False`, and `request.scheme` returns HTTP, even though i made sure it's VPS.

What could be the reason for that? Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MY.SERVER.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto           $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/proj/myproj.sock;

    }
}
```

And i also made sure to add to my Django settings `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')`. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Isn't port 80 always going to be http?

Comment: I tried without listen 80 but the problem is still there

Comment: Even when listening on 443?

Comment: Yep, starting to think the problem might be with cloudflare

Comment: Have you tried to put this settings `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` in `settings.py`? This will force all the http requests to be https.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. And, it looks like, I found out why it doesn't work as expected.

Accordingly to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_scheme), `$scheme` equals either `http` or `https`.

In the case of a `location`, which is declared in `server` that listens on `80` port, we get `$scheme` equal to `http`. Then, AFAIU, Django receives `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header which equals to `http`, and Django treats it as unsecured (i.e. `request.is_secure()` always returns `False`). Well, at least, it started to work well when I made the following change:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
```